# How to record phone call in android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to record a phone call in android with code, more details and code is given below.

Manifest File example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="28"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage"
    />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.CallRecording"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

The `Main Activity` code is given below.:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var recorder: MediaRecorder
private var isRecording = false


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    requestPermissions()

    val makeCall : Button = findViewById(R.id.makeCall)
    makeCall.setOnClickListener{
        if(hasPermissions()){
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}

private fun hasPermissions() : Boolean{
    val recordAudioPermission = Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
    val writeToFilePermission = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    val phoneState = Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
    return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, recordAudioPermission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
             && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, writeToFilePermission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
             && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, phoneState) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
}

private fun requestPermissions(){
    val permissions = arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, 123)
}
}
```

You can see `CallReceiver Class` example below:

```
class CallReceiver() : BroadcastReceiver() {
private var isRecording = false;
private lateinit var mediaRecorder : MediaRecorder

override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    val state = intent?.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
    when(state){
        TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING -> {
            startRecording()
        }

        TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK -> {
            startRecording()
        }

        TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE ->{
            stopRecording()
        }
    }

}


 private fun startRecording() {
     mediaRecorder = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) MediaRecorder() else MediaRecorder()
     if(!isRecording){
     mediaRecorder.apply {
         setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
         setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)
         setOutputFile(getRecordingFilePath())
         setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB) }
         try {
             mediaRecorder.prepare()
             mediaRecorder.start()
         } catch (e : IOException){
             Log.d("CallRec", e.toString())
         }
     }
     isRecording = true

}

private fun getRecordingFilePath(): String {
    val dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)
    val filePath = File(dir, "testing_${System.currentTimeMillis()}" + ".mp3")
    return filePath.path
}

private fun stopRecording(){
   if(isRecording){
       mediaRecorder.stop()
       mediaRecorder.reset()
       mediaRecorder.reset()
       isRecording = false
   }
}

}
```

When a user calls or receives a call the audio must be recorded. Both the parties should be audible. And file should be saved in storage. I am new to the android dev, it is so confusing

Comment: You're using the `MIC` audio source, so you're only recording from the microphone on the device that your app is running on. There is a `VOICE_CALL` audio source, but it requires a permission that is reserved for system apps. I'm not aware of any officially supported way for regular apps to record voice calls on modern Android versions.

Comment: I did what you said but it is still not working.